# Looking to get artist_id from authenticated Spotify user account

Tags: spotify

I am looking to integrate Spotify artist data into an app. The 'artist' is authenticating with their user account, which they normally use to access their artist account. This particular artist is authenticating to Spotify via Facebook.

I can authenticate the user via our app and make requests to Spotify API with the access_token and refresh_token.

But I can't seem to find a relationship between the authenticated user and their artist_id.

Is this even possible? If not, how can we get the artist info?

`api.spotify.com/v1/me` - the required artist data is not there

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot automatic assign or search your user profile with the artist.

[On this site](https://artists.spotify.com/c/access/artist) when you are logged user you can find "you" as an artist.

IMO this action give you possibility to assign your account to Artist Profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to confirm, I am looking for the artist with the user, not the user with the artist

Answer (score 0):

with the curl you can do this:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/following?type=artist&liit=20" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer here_your_access_token"
```

To understand, look at https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-following/

Try to adapt to your app, for example, I am not using curl on my app, I am using the httparty library.